# Hamming weight equation in Z3 SMT Sovler

Tags: z3, solver, smt, hammingweight

I have a system of equations to solve in which there is some equations of hamming weight. Hamming weight is generally the number of 1's in binary representation of a number.
I tried to solve in Z3 SMT Solver, but it outputs an error stating " b'there is no current model". I am trying to find a 32-bit number with a given hamming weight and some equations.

In examples below, I am trying to find a number(0 to 2^5-1) with hamming weight equal to 3.

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
K = [BitVec('k%d'%i,5) for i in range(3)]    

Eq = [K[0]&0x1 + K[0]&0x2 + K[0]&0x4 + K[0]&0x8 + K[0]&0x10 == 3]  #
s.add(Eq)
s.check()
print(s.model())
```

This gives error "b'there is no current model".

Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Edit:
I put the hamming equation wrong; It will be

```
Eq = [(K[0]&0x1) +  ((K[0]&0x2)>>1) +  ((K[0]&0x4)>>2) +  ((K[0]&0x8)>>3) +  ((K[0]&0x10)>>4) == 3 ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the operator precedence in Python. This works:

```
Eq = [(K[0]&0x1) + (K[0]&0x2) + (K[0]&0x4) + (K[0]&0x8) + (K[0]&0x10) == 3]
```

However, you're not actually computing the hamming weight this way. Each of the terms needs to be shifted. E.g. `K[0]&0x8` is not zero or one, but `0x8` or `0x0`.

Comment: Yes I noticed it, hamming weight equation will be ```Eq = [(K[0]&0x1) +  ((K[0]&0x2)>>1) +  ((K[0]&0x4)>>2) +  ((K[0]&0x8)>>3) +  ((K[0]&0x10)>>4) == 3 ]
``` . Thanks, I was getting error because of operator precedence.